# Open XML String in Web Browser

Tags: xml, string, browser

I have an XML string and can convert the whole string to a hyperlink. When clicked on, is there a way I can open it in a browser formatted as an XML?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can with some browsers and with some plugins. There is an xml viewer plugin for both firefox and chrome. Do set the header to type xml though instead of html.

Answer (score 0):

Well there is no general defined formatting for XML, if the XML is not a format like XHTML or SVG or MathML the browser knows to render and if it is not styled with CSS or XSLT then browser usually show the source as a collapsible tree:

```html
<a href="data:application/xml;base64,PHJvb3QgeG1sbnM9Imh0dHA6Ly9leGFtcGxlLmNvbS8iPg0KICA8ZWxlbWVudCBhdHQxPSJ2YWx1ZTEiPmZvbzwvZWxlbWVudD4NCjwvcm9vdD4=">Example link with data URL representing an XML document</a>
```

That works fine for me with Mozilla browsers like Firefox, IE however complains and refuses to render anything, Chrome renders the text content of the XML instead of its source tree.

Comment: The XML is a hyperlink. So, the browser just passes the whole XML in the address bar. Is there anything I can do within the XML string so that even when it passes the whole xml string in the address bar; it still opens it as an xml.

Comment: As I have shown in my example, you can use a `data` URL. However, it looks as if the support differs in browsers, only Mozilla browsers like Firefox do load the XML and render the source in a collapsible tree view.